# Akka how to reach remote actors in cluster

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

First I would like to say that I am very new to Akka and actors :)

I would like to create a distributed application. I will split the application in a web part(REST API) and a user management part. But what is the right way to access an actor from another part of the application?

I know that I can access an actor selection by providing its address (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting.html#looking-up-remote-actors), but isn't there a way where I don't have to work with addresses?

I just want to create a system where it is very easy to reach a remote actor without using their addresses.

Comment: Address is a way to describe _which_ actor you want to reach. So, what you are asking seems to be wether there is a way to reach an actor without specifying which one you want. I don't think so :)

Comment: In order to access remote actor, you must know where is that actor is, and address is a way to to identify that. How do you expect to get reference of remote actor without out its address?

Comment: @RaKa I have some actor that will only have a single instance, so i though maybe I can reach them by their class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cluster Sharding the actor identity is `persistanceId` and must be part of message which you send to whole cluster. Thats why you need to define `extractEntityId`.

Read more in documentation:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html

Comment: It's worth to mention Cluster Sharding has some overhead but you dont need to worry about specific actor location (address) system resolves it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look for [Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/distributed-pub-sub.html)

But the limit is: your local actorsystem which hosts your local actor & the remote actorsystem which hosts your remote actor should be configured as an `akka cluster`.

If cluster could be your design, then you can do as follows:

Remote Part:

```
class Subscriber extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import DistributedPubSubMediator.{ Subscribe, SubscribeAck }
  val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator
  // subscribe to the topic named "content"
  mediator ! Subscribe("content", self)

  def receive = {
    case s: String ⇒
      log.info("Got {}", s)
    case SubscribeAck(Subscribe("content", None, `self`)) ⇒
      log.info("subscribing")
  }
}
```

Local Part:

```
class Publisher extends Actor {
  import DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish
  // activate the extension
  val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator

  def receive = {
    case in: String ⇒
      val out = in.toUpperCase
      mediator ! Publish("content", out)
  }
}
```

The remote part actor subscribe `content topic`, and if local part want to talk with remote, it can just publish message to `content topic`.

Hope it gives you some thoughts.